# Are there any plugins in eclipse that will allow me to edit java classes graphically?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Are there any eclipse plugins out there that will allow me to edit a java class or java classes graphically? Basically what I would like to do is to click on one or more java classes from the package explorer and see a property window that shows the interfaces that it extends, fields it defines, method definitions, etc... I could then click in this grid and then add interfaces, fields etc... Preferably I'd like to be able to edit multiple classes at once this way.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: also take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697824/uml-plugin-for-eclipse-class-diagrams-java-code-generation-indigo-juno

Answer (score 0):

[Borland Together](http://borland.com/products/together/) exists as a set of Eclipse plugins, and allows you to modify the code in the form of UML documents. From the FAQ:

> Together extends team effectiveness by supporting multiple languages
>   (Java®, C++ and CORBA®/IDL) and platforms (Eclipse™ 4.3.1 on all
>   supported Eclipse platforms).